# How to iterate through Tuple<List<String>> in Python

Tags: python

```
class App:
    def filter(*input):
        result = []
        print(type(input))
        for arrayOfColors in input:
            print(type(arrayOfColors))
            goodColors = getGoodColors(arrayOfColors)
            result.add(goodColors)
        return result

def getGoodColors(arrayOfColors):
    setOfNotGoodColors = ["gray", "yellow", "purple"]
    goodColors = []
    for color in arrayOfColors:
        if color not in setOfNotGoodColors:
            goodColors.add(color)
    return goodColors
        
app = App()
app.filter(["blue", "red"], ["gray","blue"])
```

The result of compilation is:

```
<class '__main__.App'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
File "<string>", line 7, in filter
  File "<string>", line 14, in getGoodColors
TypeError: 'App' object is not iterable
```

How to get rid of this error?
I have to write more not code characters, please help.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve. Please give input and expected output.

Comment: `input` is a name of a built-in python function. Dont use it as variable name.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: Use `def filter(self, *input):` notice the missing `self`. But more is wrong here.

Comment: also `list.append` not `list.add()`

Comment: `filter` that you are using points to python filter - https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/filter

Comment: adding self param and change method append instead of add helps to compile file :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a python class every method should have a `self` parameter, for example:

```
class App:
    def filter(self, *input):
```

with the self parameter you can reach the properties of that instance.

another problem is: in order to add a value to a python list you need to use the function `append`, for example:

```
goodColors.append(color)
```

Your final code should look something like this:

```
class App:
    def filter(self, *input):
        result = []
        print(type(input))
        for arrayOfColors in input:
            print(type(arrayOfColors))
            goodColors = getGoodColors(arrayOfColors)
            result.append(goodColors)
        return result

def getGoodColors(arrayOfColors):
    setOfNotGoodColors = ["gray", "yellow", "purple"]
    goodColors = []
    for color in arrayOfColors:
        if color not in setOfNotGoodColors:
            goodColors.append(color)
    return goodColors
        
app = App()
app.filter(["blue", "red"], ["gray","blue"])
```

Note: You shouldn't use the name input as a paramter because it is the name of a built-in function, but the code runs even if you use it so I didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the problem if you add `print(input)` right under `def filter(*input):`; you'll see

```
(<__main__.App object at 0x00000211E39C0A48>, ['blue', 'red'], ['gray', 'blue'])
```

That is the result of `self` in every class. You can avoid it in your `for` loop with a slice of `[1:]`. Also, python `list`s have no attribute called `add`; they are called `append`:

```
class App:
    def filter(*input):
        result = []
        for arrayOfColors in input[1:]:
            goodColors = getGoodColors(arrayOfColors)
            result.append(goodColors)
        return result

def getGoodColors(arrayOfColors):
    setOfNotGoodColors = ["gray", "yellow", "purple"]
    goodColors = []
    for color in arrayOfColors:
        if color not in setOfNotGoodColors:
            goodColors.append(color)
    return goodColors
        
app = App()
app.filter(["blue", "red"], ["gray","blue"])
```

Note that it is a bad practice to name your variables names that are taken by built-ins, so that `input` variable would be better off named as `my_input`.